# reactJS - JSX map array to form elements but group each four elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I wanna create a form with around 30 elements with semantic-ui like this:

```
     <Form.Input
        id="survive"
        type="number"
        label="survive"
        required
      />
```

So I thought of creating an array containing all `Form.Input` id and `map` them like this:

```
return (
        myArray.map((element) => {
           <Form.Input id={element} label={element} type="number"/>
        })
```

How can I group every four elements together with the array.map() function?
Manually it would work like this but I'm sure there's a more efficient way as do it manually like this

```
<Form.Group>
    <Form.Input id="1"/>
    <Form.Input id="2"/>
    <Form.Input id="3"/>
    <Form.Input id="4"/>
</Form.Group>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that with just `.map(..)` because `.map(..)` returns an array that has the same number of elements as the original array and the expected result is an array that has `myArray.length / 4` number of elements.

To achieve this, you can use a combination of [`.reduce(..)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and `.map(..)`, here is an example:

```
myArray.reduce((a, c, i) => {
  if (i % 4 === 0) {
    a.push([]);
  }
  a[a.length - 1].push(c);
  return a;
}, []).map((arr) => (
  <Form.Group>
    {arr.map(element => (<Form.Input id={element} label={element} type="number"/>))}
  </Form.Group>
))
```

What this does is to first create a 2 dimensional array (the inner arrays have 4 elements) and then map both the first and second dimension.

Answer (score 0):

you could do this

```
return <Form.Group>
{
    myArray.map((element , index) => {
           return <Form.Input key={index} id={element} label={element} type="number"/>
    }
}
</Form.Group>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could map over chunk of array.

Chunk function taken from [here](https://www.w3resource.com/javascript-exercises/fundamental/javascript-fundamental-exercise-265.php).

```
const chunk = (arr, size) => Array.from({ length: Math.ceil(arr.length / size) }, (v, i) =>
arr.slice(i * size, i * size + size)
);
```

Map over chunks of 4 and form groups

```
chunk(myArray).map(ch=>{
    //Return a group
    <Form.Group>
    {ch.map(element=>{
        //return element
    })}
    </Form.Group>
}
```